# How to pick every time new or unique random item from a array list in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to pick a new item from a list that hasn't been picked already until there are no more.

Here is my code:

```
private var quizQuestionList: ArrayList<Quiz> 
private var pickedItems: ArrayList<Int>
private var random: Random = Random()

private fun pickItem(): Quiz {
    var index = random?.nextInt(quizQuestionList!!.size)

    if (pickedItems.contains(index)) {
        index = random?.nextInt(quizQuestionList!!.size)
        pickedItems.add(index)
    } else {
        pickedItems.add(index)
    }

    val item = quizQuestionList!!.get(index!!)
    return item
}
```

Please suggest any solution that gives me a new item every time. I used an int list for all previously picked items and check every time when picked new item but I didn't get success.

Comment: my code is
private var quizQuestionList: ArrayList<Quiz>
private var pickedItems: ArrayList<Int>
private var random: Random = Random()

private fun pickItem(): Quiz {
    var index = random?.nextInt(quizQuestionList!!.size)
    if (pickedItems.contains(index)) {
        index = random?.nextInt(quizQuestionList!!.size)
        pickedItems.add(index)
    } else {
        pickedItems.add(index)
    }
    val item = quizQuestionList!!.get(index!!)
    return item
}

Comment: edit your question to add the code

Comment: am not able to add the code on question i have already tried many times. so i put my code on comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't obvious what you are looking for, but it looks like you want to show different Quiz question from ArrayList. In condition of, when that question is shown, no more same question will be shown. Here is how you should do, I will give you just the logic you could try it yourself:

```
import java.util.Random

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val random = Random()
    var randomInt: Int
    var pickedInt: MutableSet<Int> = mutableSetOf()

    fun rand(from: Int, to: Int): Int{
        do{
            randomInt = random.nextInt(to - from) + from
        }while(pickedInt.contains(randomInt))

        pickedInt.add(randomInt)
        return randomInt
    }

    while(pickedInt.size < 9){
        var differentNumber = rand(1,11)
        println(differentNumber)
    }
}
```

This will print nine different Number. The way I choosing MutableSet is because it will only have unique values, no duplicated value. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanku @willy
its working for me.
but can you please more explain one thing on your code.
random.nextInt(to - from) + from,
how this line is work i mean what is returned by this

Answer (score 1):

here is code for same::

```
val arrayList = ArrayList<String>()
   arrayList.add("a")
    arrayList.add("b")
    arrayList.add("c")
    arrayList.add("d")
    arrayList.add("e")
    arrayList.add("f")
    arrayList.add("g") 
    arrayList.add("h") 
    arrayList.add("i")
    arrayList.add("j") 
    arrayList.add("k") 
    random = Random()

    Low = 0
    High = arrayList.size


    val generateRandom = findViewById<View>(R.id.generateRandom) as Button
    generateRandom.setOnClickListener {
        val Result = random.nextInt(High - Low) + Low

        Log.v("check", arrayList[Result])
    }
```

Please let me know if need more!!

Comment: thanks @ankit
could you please explain.
random.nextInt(High - Low) + Low. 
How it is work, because if high=10, and always low=0, then (10-0)+0 always return high value, if high is changed to 15 then it return 15. i am not understand it please explain it.

Comment: first time it always goes to high value because it Random class functionality, then it will start with random value generation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var arrayList = ArrayList<String>()
    private var lastItem = -1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        for (i in 0..9) {
            arrayList.add(i.toString())
        }
        btnData.setOnClickListener {
            Log.e("RANDOM_NUMBER", "" + getRandomItemFromList())
        }
    }

    private fun getRandomItemFromList(): Int {
        val randomValue = Random().nextInt(arrayList.size)

        return if (randomValue != lastItem) {
            lastItem = randomValue
            randomValue
        } else {
            getRandomItemFromList()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this extension for the ArrayList class in Kotlin you can use it multiple times in only one line.

```
fun <T> ArrayList<T>.generateRandomItems(numberOfItems: Int): ArrayList<T> {
val range = if(numberOfItems > this.size){this.size}else{numberOfItems}
val randomItems = ArrayList<T>()
for (i in 0..range) {
    var randomItem: T
    do {
        randomItem = this.random()
    } while (randomItems.contains(randomItem))
    randomItems.add(randomItem)
}
return randomItems
}
```

**Usage:**

```
 val randomUsersList = usersList.generateRandomItems(20)
```

**Note:** the usersList is the list that has items to generate random items from.